# Hadoop final property overriding using System.setProperty()

Tags: configuration, hadoop

It is possible for System administrators to define certain properties as final, so that client daemons may not override them.

However properties set using `System.setProperty()` method take preference over those set using Hadoop's configuration API, in that case is it not possible for a client daemon to override a final property by setting it by calling `System.setProperty()`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that while configuration properties can be defined in terms of system properties,
unless system properties are redefined using configuration properties, they are not accessible
through the configuration API

Internally, the hadoop system will access the configuration properties only through the Configuration interface. In case the user was unable to modify a configuration property through the Configuration interface (and he will be unable if the property is defined as final by the admin) the system will not see the modification the user made in the System's properties

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would that mean that while you are incorporating System properties as Hadoop properties using Configuration API, it would detect a final property being re-set by client daemon and flash error?

Comment: I think it will simply ignore the system's properties. Only the systems properties redefined in the conf object will be visible to the system. If a configuration property set in the conf object re-sets an existing Systems property then it will be visible otherwise it won't. The user can modify as many properties as he wants with System.setProperty() they will simply invisible to the hadoop framework because they weren't set through the conf obj.